# How do I listen for the blur event on the entire form?

Tags: javascript

`<input>` fields have an `onblur` event that you can listen to to detect when it's no longer in focus. How would I know whether the user simply pressed tab and went to the next `<input>` as opposed to clicking completely outside the form?

For context, I'm trying to trigger validation & save when the user moves away from the form, but I don't want to attempt to do it before they've had a chance to fill the whole thing out (some fields depend on others).

In my particular example, I'm actually using `contenteditable` `<td>`s, but they still have the `onblur` event, so I'm looking to do it on the parent `<tr>`.

Comment: Put click/focus event to element that is outside of your form

Comment: Are you open to use a framework like jquery or zepto?

Comment: @PerHornshøj-Schierbeck sure - I'll probably end up translating it to vanilla JS but a jQuery answer would be just as valid

Comment: @Justinas I like where you're going, but what element? How would I know what they click on? In fact, there aren't any other `<input>` type elements on the page, so not even sure anything else _has_ an `onfocus` event.

Comment: @TobiasFünke But `div` has `onClick` event

Comment: Do you want to catch the event when the user TABs out of the last element? I'm not sure excatly when you want the take action?

Answer (score 0):

use this class =>  'form-element'  for every form element.

```
$('.form-element').blur(function(){
  // your action
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but wouldn't that trigger every time a user tabs between elements?

Comment: Yes it would - but you could pair this with more testing against the criterias you have for having the form correctly filled out.